# How to import a piano sound from a VST plugin into a synth?

Tags: piano, synthesizer, daw, vst, samples

I am using a Roland XPS 10 synth that allows us to import sounds sampled from VST plugins into the memory of the synth and play. From what I know right now, the file that I have to export from the DAW and copy into my synth has to be a **.wav** file. However, I have no clue how I can create a file from the VST plugin I have, which I can play using a midi keyboard on my DAW, to create a .wav sample to play on my synth.

I saw a video where a person demonstrated it with a flute VST. They first added a virtual instrument track and then, in the piano roll, drew a 1 second long note on **C4** and simply exported the project as a **.wav** file. He then copied it into the synth's memory and boom! It worked. However, the same thing didn't work with piano VSTS.

**What is the standard way of sampling a sound from a piano VST plugin to use on a synth? What steps should I follow and what software (DAW) should I use?**

Answer (score 3):

Because the flute can be considered (if we exclude the initial breath noise) as a single waveform that can be repeated or extended without too much problem, it is very easy to import it as a sample. The synth can then play it for as long as needed. It's basic, but it works.

Piano, however, has attack, decay, sustain and release (ADSR) so just playing the sample will not work, it would sound like you were just mashing the key over and over again.

If you want to use a piano VST for a sample you need to be aware of these sections, and set them up appropriately so your synth knows to play the attack, then how long to decay to the sustain level (which can be held) before releasing the note. MIDI can send ADSR signals, and I think the XPS10 handles them correctly, so can you explain what doesn't work when you try this.

As to which DAW to use - the main ones all have full ADSR, so this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Often thought that a flute sound could be one of the simplest to replicate or sample. Wonder which is even easier. +1

Comment: You can sort of get away with violin as well - but you miss the attack noise you expect from the bow starting to move

Comment: Probably easier with a bank of violins than a single one? Most of my synths' violin sounds are more convincing if there's a dozen or more violins at a time, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ahhh... brings back memories :) Crushing an entire GM sample set into 1MB ROM... those were the days. Attack portion, then find a loop as short as possible, sometimes a single wave cycle. ADSR applied at output, computationally. [Alchemy](http://macos9lives.com/smforum/index.php?topic=2121.0) used to be the tool of choice

Comment: Ohhh - I'd totally forgotten Alchemy!

Comment: I understand that looping will not work for a piano sample. But how exactly do I export the sample? I mean I have the plugin open in my DAW (Reaper). What next? I'm totally clueless.

Comment: When you tried the process you described in the video, what happened? Exporting as a wav is normal.